# Spring boot - RouterFunction - matching

Tags: spring-boot

Using Spring boot 2.7.x with spring spring-boot-starter-web

I got an endpoint that accept any GET Request defined with

```
@GetMapping("/**" )
```

Then I got Swagger

```
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.13")
```

My issue is that when I try to navigate to the swagger page ... matchs the GET endpoint ...

I'm thinking of using `RouterFunction` but I can't figure out how to not mach a route ... for the swagger

Any suggestions ?

Comment: One way that you can try is to exclude the `Swagger UI` resources from the Spring MVC dispatcher servlet. To do so, configure the resources handler to map the Swagger to non MVC endpoint

Comment: Thank you for the response, 

Can you illustrate how to do it ? 

I was checking 


     @Configuration
     class MyConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {

    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
  registry
   .addResourceHandler("/another")
   .setCachePeriod(3600)
   .resourceChain(true)
   .addResolver(PathResourceResolver())
 }

Can't figure out how ...